# how to handle null value in many to many relationship

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, many-to-many, null-coalescing-operator

I am trying to achieve something like this:
if there is a matching id then filter result according to it otherwise bypass the condition

```
.Where(x => x.NeighbourhoodId == (id ?? x.NeighbourhoodId)
```

but i am not getting correct syntax with many to many relationship:

```
    public JsonResult GetPost(int? id, int? tagid)
    {
    var ret = from data in db.Posts.Include(x => x.Tags)
                 .Include(x => x.Neighbourhood)
                 .OrderByDescending(x => x.PostedDate)
                 .Where(x => x.NeighbourhoodId == (id ?? x.NeighbourhoodId)
                 && x.Tags.Any(t => t.TagId == tagid))
                 .ToList()
                 select new
                  {
                      TagName = string.Join(",", data.Tags.Select(t => t.TagName)),
                      Message = data.Message,
                    // and other related stuff
                   }
```

here, as u can see,this where clause contains multiple conditions i want to filter post.There will be only one parameter with value. means if id parameter have value then tagid will be null and if tagid is null then id would have some value.

now, i want if there is null value in tagid then still this query should run. right now, its not working becoz in database, there is no post with empty tagid or null .how to do it. any suggestions??

Comment: Please rephrase the question. What should happen when `id` is `null`? When `tagId` is `null`? Bypass the corresponding conditions?

Comment: @IvanStoev i have edited the question at end plz have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you need to build the filter dynamically based on the passed parameters like this

```
var posts = db.Posts
    .Include(x => x.Tags)
    .Include(x => x.Neighbourhood)
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.PostedDate);
if (id != null)
    posts = posts.Where(x => x.NeighbourhoodId == id.Value);
if (tagid != null)
    posts = posts.Where(x => x.Tags.Any(t => t.TagId == tagid.Value));
var ret = from data in posts
    // ... the rest
```

Comment: well, it would works i have tried it earlier before but i was looking for any solution with something with null coalescing operator btw upvote from me thnk u

Comment: @duke null coalescing and other "embedded" argument check tricks generate very poor SQL queries. I would suggest you using the approach above anytime you have a dynamic filtering - it "costs" only a few lines of code but produces optimal faster queries.

Comment: Well thnks for the response, main reason i was trying to use null coalescing operator becoz i thought it was fast if u r saying that using if statement would result in faster optimal queries then i would definitly use them @Ivan Stoev